# Android: TextInputLayout different spacing of different inputTypes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

my problem is that with I want the spacing of the `TextInputLayout`s to be exactly the same regardless of the `inputType`.

[image]

Right now:

1. The space in `android:inputType="textPassword"` between the text and the line is bigger than the spacing between those two in `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`
2. The same goes with the spacing betweeen the text and the label.

How can I make both spacings equal?

My XML for both fields:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_login"
                style="@style/text_input_layout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image_app_logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:errorEnabled="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_login"
                    style="@style/app_edit_text"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxLength="@integer/max_characters_in_edit_text"
                    android:privateImeOptions="nm"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_login_password"
                style="@style/text_input_layout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_login"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorTextTiny">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text_password"
                    style="@style/app_edit_text"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLength="@integer/max_characters_in_edit_text" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: May be this issue because of `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`  **try to remove it and run project**

Comment: @ND1010_ yes that does remove the issue, however, it also makes the eye icon disappear from the password edittext (and I must have that visible)

Comment: Ok wait i will post my answer for that

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size15"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorblueLight
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:inputType="textPassword"
                 android:longClickable="false"
                 android:maxLines="1"
                 android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

if you want to change color of `passwordToggle` than

```
private TextInputLayout inputPassword;
inputPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_input_password);

inputPassword.setPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled(true);
inputPassword.setPasswordVisibilityToggleTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorWhite)));
```

Comment: unfortunately I can see no `TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout` in styles. The only one I can use that has a `TextInputLayout` is `@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout` which doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: `<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorblueLight</item>` is just **customization of my editText text change text color**

Comment: @Simon is it helpful ?

Comment: this does not work since I don't want to change the color of the eye icon, I only want the spacing I listed to be equal as the spacing of a normal `textInputLayout`

Comment: yes , @Simon do not change color of it, its just for informing peruse

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by setting `android:paddingBottom="10dp"` and `android:paddingTop="10dp"` of the upper `EditText`.
Althought I would like to point out that this solution is obviously an ugly one - I would still appreciate a better approach.